# Flawed random number generator?

Tags: python, random, probability, proof, correctness

I used [this](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/01/22/weighted-random-generation-in-python/) weighted random number generator.

```
import random

def weighted_choice(weights):
    totals = []
    running_total = 0

    for w in weights:
        running_total += w
        totals.append(running_total)

    rnd = random.random() * running_total
    for i, total in enumerate(totals):
        if rnd < total:
            return i
```

as follows:

```
# The meaning of this dict is a little confusing, so here's the explanation:
# The keys are numbers and values are weights of its occurence and values - 1
# are weights of its disoccurence. You can imagine it like biased coins
# (except for 2 which is fair coin).
probabilities = { 0 : 1.0, 1 : 1.0, 2 : 0.5, 3 : 0.45, 4 : 0.4, 5 : 0.35,
                    6 : 0.3, 7 : 0.25, 8 : 0.2, 9 : 0.15, 10 : 0.1
                  }
  numberOfDeactivations = []
  for number in probabilities.keys():
    x = weighted_choice([probabilities[number], 1 - probabilities[number]])
    if x == 0:
      numberOfDeactivations.append(number)
  print "chance for ", repr(numberOfDeactivations)
```

I see quite often `7`, `8`, `9`, `10` in the result.

Is there some proof or guarantee that this is correct to probability theory?

Comment: What is "quite often"?  Do you have a histogram you can show us?

Comment: Obligatory: http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Important is the proof. Histogram is sufficient for proofing this?

Comment: Are you just noticing 7s, 8s, 9s, and 10s or are you running it for, say, millions of iterations and comparing the frequencies against `probabilities`?

Comment: @ousef I tried about 20 iterations and expected to see 7, 8, 9, 10 not so often.

Comment: Are you trying to prove that it is random or are you trying to prove that it is correctly distributed?  That would decide your approach - whether to research Python's RNG or the distributor function.

Comment: @xralf: 20 is nowhere near enough.  Run it a million times, and plot a histogram.

Comment: 20 iterations are *nothing*. Increase the number (millions...) to start seeing statistically significative data. You should use uniformity fitting tests for more serious intents :) .

Comment: Try it millions of times an count up the appearances of each, see if the resulting counts approach your expected weightings.

Comment: Its weird that unwanted numbers are more often than I expected.

Comment: @xralf: With only 20 iterations, it's not at all weird...

Comment: The number `10` was in 3 trials from 4 in succession with probability 0.1, it looks like something wrong is with it. But maybe not, maybe it's only iregular.

Comment: @xralf: Like I suggested, try running it a million times, and get back to us with your results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mathematically correct.  It's an application of [*inverse transform sampling*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) (although the reason it works in this case should be relatively intuitive).

I don't know Python, so I can't say whether there are any subtleties that make this particualr implementation invalid.

Comment: How do you know that `random` in Python uses this?

Comment: @xralf: Uses what?  Python `random` is a uniform RNG.  The above code is the inverse transform sampling.

Comment: And how will Python manage this `uniformity`? With uniform it's not easy to recognize there is a flaw but when you use weights it's easy to see that the "light" numbers behave like "heavy" here (at least heavier than I thought). Does it depend on the frequency of running this application? Is there something that could corrupt randomness? Or could this `Inverse transform sampling` corrupt `Python`s ` `uniform RNG`?

Comment: @xralf: Python manages uniformity by using an algorithm that generates a uniform distribution.  I have no idea what you mean by "corrupt Python's uniform RNG"; you simply have some code that operates on the output of `random`.

Comment: Maybe rather vice versa. `Python uniform RNG` could corrupt this `inverse transform sampling` if it wasn't uniform enough. How do I recognize that it's really uniform?

Comment: @xralf: By plotting a histogram.  But I assure you, the Python RNG is fine, at least for the purposes of this experiment.

Comment: I would bet that if I would through a bad dice with 0.1 probability of six, I would see six most of the time. But is there a dice in the computer or something similar?

Comment: @xralf: An example of the kind of algorithm that `random` uses is [Mersenne twiseter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) (but I don't know for sure).  But why don't you just plot the histograms?

Comment: OK, it seems that the distribution is correct for large number of trials. I hope that no conditions are repeated when I'm running the application. In small number of trials it's not as expected, but maybe I can decrease probabilities.

Comment: Because plotting histogram needs time. I can log the values every day and see in some larger period of running the program (I have to use the situation of application usage, not quick generation of 1000 values).

Comment: @xralf: Plotting a histogram doesn't take a large amount of time.  Just make a test app that runs that function a large number of times.

Comment: I thought adding a few values to the plot every day, because this is the usage of the application.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: as a side note: I think your code is equivalent to

```
import random
probabilities = { 0 : 1.0, 1 : 1.0, 2 : 0.5, 3 : 0.45, 4 : 0.4, 5 : 0.35,
                    6 : 0.3, 7 : 0.25, 8 : 0.2, 9 : 0.15, 10 : 0.1}
numberOfDeactivations=filter(
         lambda kv:random.random()<=probabilities[kv] , probabilities)
```

**Original answer:**

The method is correct. Below is a complete example, creating the frequency table and comparing it with the requested weights.

With 100000 iterations there's nothing indicating that you don't get what you requested. The 'expected' is the probability you requested, 'got' is the fraction of times you actually got that value. Ratio should be close to 1 and it is:

```
  0, expected: 0.2128 got: 0.2107 ratio: 1.0100
  1, expected: 0.2128 got: 0.2145 ratio: 0.9921
  2, expected: 0.1064 got: 0.1083 ratio: 0.9825
  3, expected: 0.0957 got: 0.0949 ratio: 1.0091
  4, expected: 0.0851 got: 0.0860 ratio: 0.9900
  5, expected: 0.0745 got: 0.0753 ratio: 0.9884
  6, expected: 0.0638 got: 0.0635 ratio: 1.0050
  7, expected: 0.0532 got: 0.0518 ratio: 1.0262
  8, expected: 0.0426 got: 0.0418 ratio: 1.0179
  9, expected: 0.0319 got: 0.0323 ratio: 0.9881
 10, expected: 0.0213 got: 0.0209 ratio: 1.0162

 A total of 469633 numbers where generated for this table.
```

Here's the code:

```
import random

def weighted_choice(weights):
    totals = []
    running_total = 0
    for w in weights:
        running_total += w
        totals.append(running_total)
    rnd = random.random() * running_total
    for i, total in enumerate(totals):
        if rnd < total:
            return i


counts={ k:0 for k in range(11)}
probabilities = { 0 : 1.0, 1 : 1.0, 2 : 0.5, 3 : 0.45, 4 : 0.4, 5 : 0.35,
                    6 : 0.3, 7 : 0.25, 8 : 0.2, 9 : 0.15, 10 : 0.1
                  }

for x in range(100000):
  numberOfDeactivations = []
  for number in probabilities.keys():
    x = weighted_choice([probabilities[number], 1 - probabilities[number]])
    if x == 0:
      numberOfDeactivations.append(number)
  for k in numberOfDeactivations:
    counts[k]+=1.0

sums=sum(counts.values())
counts2=[x*1.0/sums for x in counts.values()]

print "ratio expected frequency to requested:":

# make the probabilities real probabilities instead of weights:
psum=sum(probabilities.values())
for k in probabilities:
    probabilities[k]=probabilities[k]/psum

for k in probabilities:
    print "%3d, expected: %6.4f got: %6.4f ratio: %6.4f" %(k,probabilities[k],counts2[k], probabilities[k]/counts2[k])
```

Comment: I wrote a comment in question describing the dictionary. Probabilities or the values in the dictionary. So, 0 has probability 1, 1 has probability 1, 2 has probability 0.5 (fair coin) etc. The dictionary items are independent. I wanted to only illustrate broader context, though it was sufficient to write only one item from the dictionary.